# Eclipse/runtime só atualiza HTML após reiniciar

Tags: jsf, eclipse, tomcat

Boa noite! Não sei se alguém vai conseguir me ajudar, mas é bom tentar. Tenho um projeto `JSF` no Eclipse há anos, sempre que atualizo um `XHTML` a mudança era refletida no navegador.

De ontem para hoje as mudanças no `XHTML` pararam de ser refletidas, apenas muda após reiniciar o servidor.

Inicialmente pensei ser um problema na configuração de alguma opção do `Tomcat`, que estava usando como `Runtime`, porém passei mesmo colocando a opção de publicação para publicar automaticamente a cada alteração no arquivo, marcando para o eclipse da refresh automático e também `build` automático, não funciona. Só altera depois de reiniciar o servidor.

O clean funciona porém reinicia o servidor.

Cheguei até a fazer uma nova instalação do Eclipse, configurando novamente o projeto e usando outro servidor como `runtime`, o `Pivotal Server`, porém o problema persiste. Só muda a página depois que reinicio o servidor.

Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser? Existe possibilidade de ser algo no `web.xml`?

Comment: Você inicia o Tomcat em modo debug? O teu Tomcat é configurado no Eclipse mesmo?

Comment: Sim, no modo debug e é configurado no próprio Eclipse. Mas como falei não parece ser nada haver com o Tomcat em si, pois trocando o server para o Pivotal tc Server o problema continua.